# File Watcher in Oozie

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

**Scenario :** 
Input Files : file1.log , file2.log

I want to trigger a Co-ordinator only when the above 2 input files are present.Is to possible to make as a file watcher ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You could definitely do this. The Input events of a coordinator application specify the input conditions that are required in order to execute a coordinator action. Here is an example from GITHUB
https://github.com/yahoo/oozie/wiki/Oozie-Coord-Use-Cases

```
$ cat coordinator.xml
<coordinator-app name="MY_APP" frequency="1440" start="2009-02-01T00:00Z" end="2009-02-07T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
   <datasets>
      <dataset name="input1" frequency="60" initial-instance="2009-01-01T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
         <uri-template>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/revenue_feed/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}/${HOUR}</uri-template>
         <done-flag>trigger.dat</done-flag>
      </dataset>
   </datasets>
   <input-events>
      <data-in name="coordInput1" dataset="input1">
          <start-instance>${coord:current(-23)}</start-instance>
          <end-instance>${coord:current(0)}</end-instance>
      </data-in>
   </input-events>
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/workflows</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>     
</coordinator-app>
```